# using Javascript fetch api how can I add a hyperlink to each element o f returned array?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Using fetch, I get the following array from an api call:

```
[
  "BN16 1AA",
  "BN16 1AB",
  "BN16 1AD",
  "BN16 1AE",
  "BN16 1AF",
  "BN16 1AG",
  "BN16 1AH",
  "BN16 1AJ",
  "BN16 1AL",
  "BN16 1AQ"
]
```

here it appears vertically but when I add it to my web page with

```
document.body.append(myarr[i])
```

it appears horizontally like this:

```
BN16 1AABN16 1ABBN16 1ADBN16 1AEBN16 1AFBN16 1AGBN16 1AHBN16 1AJBN16 1ALBN16 1AQ
```

So I would like to do two things:

1) present each item vertically 
and 
2) add either a hyperlink: `<a href=myfunc(val)>val</a>` or onclick event preferably

Here is the full code:

```js
fetch('http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/BN16/autocomplete')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    arr = data.result
    let myarr = arr;
    for (let i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
      document.body.append(myarr[i])
    }
  });
```

I have attempted, in multiple ways, to add the hyperlink including:

```
document.body.append(myarr[i]).onclick = myfunc()
```

Comment: Create a `<ul>` or `<ol>` list and fill each `<li>` item with the value. Attach one click handler to the list element to handle all the clicks on list items.

Comment: thank you. How do I add the onclick handler? 
for (let i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myarr[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);

Comment: Please see my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091088/295783)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add a table to get data row wise and put `onclick` with the anchor HTML:

```js
fetch('http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/BN16/autocomplete')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    arr = data.result
    let myarr = arr;
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    for (let i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
      var anchor = document.createElement("a");
      anchor.setAttribute("onclick", "return myFunc('" + myarr[i] + "')");
      anchor.innerHTML = myarr[i];
      anchor.href = "#";
      table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + anchor.outerHTML + '<td><td>';
    }
    document.body.append(table);
  });

function myFunc(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to skin a cat.

```js
const myFunc = str => console.log(str);
const myarr = ["BN16 1AA", "BN16 1AB", "BN16 1AD", "BN16 1AE", "BN16 1AF", "BN16 1AG", "BN16 1AH", "BN16 1AJ", "BN16 1AL", "BN16 1AQ"];
myarr.forEach(code => {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.textContent = code;
  a.href = "#";
  a.setAttribute("data-code", code);
  a.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunc(this.getAttribute("data-code"))
  }
  document.body.append(a);
  document.body.append(document.createElement("br"));
});
document.body.append(document.createElement("hr"));

// Or delegated
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "container"
document.body.append(div);
let html = myarr.map(code => `<a href="#" data-code="${code}">${code}</a><br/>`)
div.innerHTML = html.join("");
div.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunc(e.target.getAttribute("data-code"));
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, so many great answers and different each in approach. I have learnt a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Strange you chose to accept the poorest solution :/

Answer (score 1):

I do not like using hyperlinks only to trigger a function, so I would prefer adding a click event to the list.

```js
const myFunc = value => {
  console.log( `the user clicked ${ value }` );
};

const arr = [
  "BN16 1AA",
  "BN16 1AB",
  "BN16 1AD",
  "BN16 1AE",
  "BN16 1AF",
  "BN16 1AG",
  "BN16 1AH",
  "BN16 1AJ",
  "BN16 1AL",
  "BN16 1AQ"
];

const items = arr.map( value => `<li data-value="${ value }">${ value }</li>` );
const list = document.createElement( 'ul' );
list.innerHTML = items.join( '' );
list.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  const value = event.target.getAttribute( 'data-value' );
  if ( value ) myFunc( value );
});
document.body.appendChild( list );
```

Comment: If A11Y is a concern, I would use buttons inside the list items to signify an action, since hyperlinks signify a link to a different resource. I usually think about screen readers and crawler bots detecting a hyperlink with a href that does not refer to a different resource, when I suggest not using hyperlinks to trigger javascript actions. But my knowledge about how exactly these work is limited, so it might not even matter.

Comment: I use links if I need a pointer and a tab index - especially if the links loads something. A button is also good

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this :

```js
fetch('http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/BN16/autocomplete')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.result.forEach((item) => {
      document.body.innerHTML += '<br><a href="#">' + item + '</a>';
    })
 });
```